# jQuery filling Div Ids with input values

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery;

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#q24").on('keypress change', function(event) {
       var data=$(this).val();
       $("#line1").text(data);
});  
});
```

which should (as far as I can tell) take the value of a single line input field called 'q24' and put that text in a div with the id 'line1'. Instead what appears to happen is when q24 is filled with the first line of an address (or anything, for that matter) the text inside the div changes to read '0' instead of blank.[image: here's the result]

Comment: Can you show your relevant html?

Comment: I'll edit the post just now.

Comment: Oh dear. Just went to grab the input text and realised I'd made a small typo on the id of the field which would have stopped the jQuery finding the initial value. upvoted your comment as you at least pointed me at my mistake!

Comment: I am not understand your ask, please edit your ask with example html code

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#q24").on('keypress change', function(event) {
           var data=$(this).val();
           $("#line1").text(data);
    });  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    Address:
    <div id="line1">

    </div>
    <input type="text" id="q24"/>
    
</body>
```